# div in html page not completely showing its content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written the following code in JSFiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/msridhar/1zvhmpjq/11/
HTML file:

```
 <body>
<div id="headerDiv">
        <img id="headerImg" src="" width="280" height="125" alt="DummyLogo"/>
        <pre id="headerPre">
                 Test Series
        Cloud Solutions
        </pre>                  
        <hr id="headerHR">
    </div>                              
        <div id="results">
        </div>      
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body { 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0; 
        height: 100%;                       
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  body{
    position: relative;
  }
      #results{         
  width: 100%;          
  height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px; 
        left: 300px;    
        overflow: auto;
      }
      body{
        position: relative;
      }               
        #headerDiv{     
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100vw;               
            //border-bottom: 3px solid #808080;
        }
        #headerHR{                                              
            width: 100%;
            height: 1px;
        }
        #headerImg{
            float: left;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        #headerPre{
            float: left;
            font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 24px;
        }
```

Javascript:

```
$('#results').load('https://fiddle.jshell.net/ds2vxqbg/1/show')
```

The code for html file loaded in Javascript is:

```
<table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Product no.</th>
        <th>Product name</th>
        <th>Product type</th>
        <th>Product Description</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Fruit</td>
        <td>Its a fruit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>Fruit</td>
        <td>Its a fruit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Pineapple</td>
        <td>Fruit</td>
        <td>Its a fruit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Pear</td>
        <td>Fruit</td>
        <td>Its a fruit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Plum</td>
        <td>Fruit</td>
        <td>Its a fruit</td>
      </tr>
    </table>          
    <img src="" width = "800" height = "600">
    <img src="" width = "800" height = "600">
    <img src="" width = "800" height = "600">
    <img src="" width = "800" height = "600">
```

I have loaded a html page in a div tag with id results. Though that div tag was enabled to overflow auto, it is not showing entire contents when scrolled. Please point out me what is the problem.

Comment: Hello!
I've tried your JSFiddle and I am able to scroll and see all the content inside the div (I've also double checked the link you're loading).
However I think your div is inheriting `overflow: hidden;` from the `html,body `tag, or you remove that from `html, body`, or you add an `!important` to the div's css.

Comment: What else is missing? I see the table is displayed on the fiddle

Comment: if you mean the 4 img tags I put a border on those on the fly ad I can see all the 4

Comment: I am really not able to see the bottom part of the 4th image. Can anyone please tell me why is that negative marking for my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#results` cuts off by `body {overflow:hidden;}` because div set width and height to 100% of body, but it has additional offset.

You can try to do next:

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="headerDiv">
        <img id="headerImg" src="" width="280" height="125" alt="DummyLogo"/>
        <pre id="headerPre">
             Test Series
            Cloud Solutions
        </pre>                  
    <hr id="headerHR">
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">  <!-- add wrapper -->
        <div id="results"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and css:

```
#wrapper {
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-left: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#results {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```